# how to convert String value into it's time value

Tags: java

I have a table called attendance in db, and there is a column called noOfHours. It's a String and there's a column called a month within. I need to calculate total no of hours for a given month, so how can I achieve that task?

Example: If an employee in the month of august works for 5 hours and 45 minutes, then the other day he works for 4 hours 30 minutes, the total number of hours should be 10 hours 15 minutes. How can I achieve this task? In my db in attendance table, within the noOfHours column those values are stored as "5h 45min", so please tell me a way to do this.

Comment: You might want to change the way your data is stored in the database. If you want numbers why store it as a `String` in the first place. Change the field to int or something and just store total number of minutes...

Comment: If that is not an option I would suggest parsing out the 5 and the 45 converting to integers then doing your calculations as needed. You can use regex to do your parsing...

Comment: So if someone works 45mins on a given month, is it displayed as "0h 45min" ?

Comment: If i not change it to int then how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You are doing unnecessary work. Change your column type to `Time`.
But answering your question, you may convert your String to a `Date` type:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h' mm'min'");
Date yourDate = dateFormat.parse(string);
```

To make it become a string again, just make `dateFormar.format(yourDate)`

To sum two dates, you must be aware that the `Date` object carries also the day information, so you must use only the hour and minute information. You can do it using the `Calendar` class.

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(), c2 = Calendar.getInstance(), sum = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(yourDate);
c2.setTime(anotherDate);
sum.setTimeInMillis(0L);

sum.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
sum.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
sum.add(Calendar.MINUTE, c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
sum.add(Calendar.MINUTE, c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Now you have your `sum` object with your total (for two days) ammount of hours and minutes worked.
Do not forget that you may have more than 24 hours, than you have to multiply the number of days contained in the `sum` by 24.

```
Integer numHours = sum.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) * 24 + sum.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
Integer numMinutes = sum.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String ret = numHours.toString() + "h " + numMinutes.toString() + "min";
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your database has value in this format : `5h 45min` then extract your `noOfHours`  column from your database and add in a `ArrayList` as shown below:

```
ArrayList<String>hrsList=new ArrayList<>();
        hrsList.add("5h 45min");
        hrsList.add("4h 30min");
        hrsList.add("3h 50min");
        int min=0;
        int hrs=0;
        for(int i=0;i<hrsList.size();i++){

            min+=Integer.parseInt(hrsList.get(i).substring(hrsList.get(i).indexOf(' ')+1, hrsList.get(i).length()-3));
            hrs+=Integer.parseInt(hrsList.get(i).substring(0,hrsList.get(i).indexOf(' ')-1));


        }
        int newMins=0;
        int newHrs=0;
        if(min>60){
            newHrs =min/60;
            newMins=min%60;
            hrs+=newHrs;
        }

        System.out.println(hrs+"h "+newMins+"min");
```

output:

```
14h 5min
```

Comment: You can use `split` and `replace` for more readable code.
`String[] c = a.split(" ");`
`int hour = Integer.parseInt(c[0].replace("h", ""));`
`int min = Integer.parseInt(c[1].replace("min", ""));`

Comment: why should we create extra string array?

Comment: For the sake of readability.  It is unlikely to have an significant impact on performance. Also, having an extra string array is the least of OP's problems.

Comment: yes there can be multiple way to do the same thing.

Comment: The OP's question suggests that this is a fairly new programmer. I would definitely agree that the extra readability would be a bigger advantage than the cost in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Duration` for this, provided you modify the `String` to be parseable by `Duration#parse()`.

Take a look at the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

This is the simplest way of converting your `String` to `Duration`:

```
    String s = "5h 23 min";
    String modified = "PT" + s.replaceFirst("min", "m").replaceAll(" *", "");
    Duration d = Duration.parse(modified);
```

Example with outputs:

```
    String s = "5h 23 min";

    System.out.println("original string: " + s);
    String modified = "PT" + s.replaceFirst("min", "m").replaceAll(" *", "");
    System.out.println("modified string: " + modified);
    Duration d = Duration.parse(modified);

    System.out.println("total hours    : " + d.toHours());
    System.out.println("total minutes  : " + d.toMinutes());
    System.out.println("minutes of hour: " + d.toMinutes() % 60);
```

You can also easily add durations together:

```
Duration sum = oneDuration.plus(anotherDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: this is not a good way to store data. If this is a database that you administer, then I would strongly suggest that you change the database value of the noOfHours. Actually, I would not even call it noOfHours. When working with dates, times or even currency, it is a good idea to store values as the smallest needed delimiter. In other words, "$3.75" should be stored as 375, and the column name could be "cents" instead of "dollars". This makes it a lot easier to perform mathematical operations with the values.

In your case, the number of minutes seems to be the smallest needed number. I would name the column "noOfMinutes", and 4h15 would simply be 255. It is always easier to store things as simple values, and translate them to readable strings, than the opposite way around.

Anyway, if that is not an option, you need to identify a pattern in your string value. Is it always the same? `int`+"h"+`whitespace`+`int`+"min" seems to be your pattern here, but I do not know what kind of checks you have when inserting data into the database. Other possible patterns might be:
`int`+"h"+`whitespace`*x+`int`+"min"
`whitespace`+`int`+"h"+`whitespace`+`int`+"min"+`whitespace`
`int`+`whitespace`+"h"+`whitespace`+`int`+"min"
`int`+"h"+`whitespace`+`int`+`whitespace`+"min"

these are just whitespace variations, but as you see, there are several things you need to watch, if you choose to store what is really a numeric value, with numeric operation needs, as a string.

Here is how you can do it, assuming that the first pattern is valid:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String time1 = "5h 45min";
        String time2 = "4h 30min";

        int totalMinutes = stringToInt(time1) + stringToInt(time2);

        String totalTime = intToString(totalMinutes);

        System.out.println(totalTime);

    }

    public static int stringToInt(String time){
        int minutes = 0;
        String[] values = time.split(" ");
        String hourString = values[0];
        String minuteString = values[1];

        hourString = hourString.replace("h", "");
        minuteString = minuteString.replace("min", "");

        minutes += Integer.parseInt(minuteString);
        minutes += (60*Integer.parseInt(hourString));

        return minutes;
    }


    public static String intToString(int value){

        int minutes = value%60;
        int hours = ((value-minutes)/60);

        return hours+"h"+" "+minutes+"min";         
    }
```

Comment: this is a good way but my problem is i don't know the actual no of inputs for this here you have mentioned time1, time2 but in my case i might have to input 30 or 20 time inputs so what is the solution for that please kind to give me a solution

Comment: Well, you already have the methods for converting one String to an integer, and back again, so all you need to do, is turn all your strings into ints, then add them up, and turn it back. Honestly, the question you ask in your comment is pretty much "Well you taught me to do 2 + 2, but how do I do 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2".

Comment: What you might need, depending on how your String values are stored, is to learn how to do for-each loops on collections. I suggest that you try that one out for yourself. It is fairly easy to learn, if you have a basic understanding of Lists and/or collections in java.